# Geodesic of metric space

Tags: geometry, metric-spaces, geodesic

The define of geodesic is in below picture which is from Wiki. I don't know why it is generalize of geodesic for Riemannian manifolds. In fact , I can't see it is the shortest when two point are enough near . Besides, the existence is not obvious, what make sure the existence of geodesic in metric space ?

> [image]

Comment: Geodesics are not the global distance minimizers, but the local distance minimizers (try with the geodesics on the sphere, or on the torus). Here it is exactly the same definition (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesic#Riemannian_geometry ) with $\gamma$ parametrized such that $g(\dot{\gamma},\dot{\gamma})$ is constant

Comment: @user1952009  I know it is not global minimizer, so I add 'when two points are enough near'.  In fact ,it is needed to prove that when $g(\dot{\gamma},\dot{\gamma})$ is constant the path is local minimizer. But there is not $g$ in metric space, so the prove in Riemann geometry is not useful .

Comment: there is no $g(u,v)$ but there is a $g(u,u)$. after all $g(\dot{\gamma},\dot{\gamma})$  is nothing more than the derivative squared of $d(\gamma(t_0),\gamma(t))$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intrinsic_metric If you just make up a random metric space, it is probably not a length space.